# How much lemon extract to substitute anise extract?

Tags: baking

I have a anise cookie recipe that I want to convert to a lemon biscotti recipe.

*How much lemon extract should I use when I use 3 teaspoons of the anise extract?*

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice!  **:-)** Could you please [edit] your question and provide the ingredients of both? (it all depends on the oil and water contents)

Comment: I normally do one of two things : (1) look for a recipe online, as they might have other considerations; (2) replace 1:1 the first time, and make a note if it's too strong/weak on the recipe so I have guidelines to adjust for the next time

Answer (score 2):

As I cook mostly only for two, I'll make a smaller batch than a recipe is intended. 3 tsp anise seems a lot, or the recipe will make a large number of cookies. Cut the recipe way down, make as small a batch as is resonable (even if you must mix by hand) taste then decide. Joe's suggestion to try 1:1 seems reasonable